# How to handle dependencies in cross platform C++ projects?

Tags: c++, git, dependencies, cmake, cross-platform

This are the ways I see for dealing with external libraries in a cross-platform project in an automated way. (Why are there no cross platform package managers?)

- **Add compiled binaries** to the repository. (This doesn't work, since platform and build configuration vary and new environments may come up.)
- **Write download scripts** to fetch source code from the internet. I could think of cloning the libraries from Github or from the projects' websites via HTTP. (This breaks when download links change. Moreover, I don't know a way to automate the build of all libraries.)
- **Include source code** of all dependencies into the repository, alternatively as sub repositories. (The problem still is to find an automated way of compiling them. Also it requires a lot of space.)

What is the workflow for handling external libraries in cross-platform C++ projects? With many big projects out there, I guess there must have emerged one. If not, based on which criteria can I decide between reasonable ways?

Comment: *"With many big cross platform projects out there, there must have emerged a standard workflow."* -- Funny.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Please clarify, because I am not experienced in this field. You seem to be somewhat familiar with this, so you could help me.

Comment: I was simply chuckling at the assumption that there is a standard workflow for this.  There is not.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Alright, I already assumed this since no one replied at this question so far. In my view package managers are a big plus on Linux. I, however, still hope that someone could answer *"[...] based on which criteria can I decide between reasonable ways?"*. Currently, I seriously consider the somewhat dirty solution of including all the libraries' source code in my repository.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616984

Comment: 7 years later and there still isn't a real answer to this question huh

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Try [CMAKE](http://www.cmake.org/)

> CMake, is a cross-platform, open-source build system. CMake is a
>   family of tools designed to build, test and package software. CMake is
>   used to control the software compilation process using simple platform
>   and compiler independent configuration files. CMake generates native
>   makefiles and workspaces that can be used in the compiler environment
>   of your choice.

Comment: I am aware of Cmake, that is why I tagged my question with it. But it doesn't seem to directly solve how to handle third party dependencies best.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, so I'm not sure what was available when asked. However, now, there are cross-platform package managers for C++.

[VCPKG](https://vcpkg.io/) is an open-source solution from Microsoft that integrates with Visual Studio & Visual Studio Code nicely, but doesn't require them. It also integrates with CMake to actually do the downloading/building that you need, if you're thinking of using CMake rather than MSBuild.

[Conan](https://conan.io/) is another open-source solution that is pretty mature. To quote the homepage:

> It works in all operating systems including Windows, Linux, OSX,
> FreeBSD, and others, and it can target any platform, including
> desktop, server, and cross-building for mobile (Android and iOS), as
> well as embedded and bare metal devices. It integrates with other
> tools like Docker, MinGW, WSL, and with all build systems such as
> CMake, MSBuild, Makefiles, Meson, SCons. It can even integrate with
> any proprietary build systems.

The other way of managing things, rather than building in the code into your source repository, is to do that via git submodules. Your build system will need to work cross-platform, but this way you get the twin benefits of very fine-grained control over version control, along with a nice path for upgrading, without cluttering your repo with other people's code. I've used this for header-only libraries for example, which don't require me to think about the build systems used by the providers of the source.